# React-native - Jest test failing upon use of useFocusEffect() - error Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jestjs

I've modified an existing react-native program. I've added `useFocusEffect()` hook to fetch data in a screen upon returning from another screen (child component). The program works as expected, however, previously written Jest test cases are failing with the following:

```
Home › should render screen without error
Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?
> 24 |   useFocusEffect(
     |   ^
  25 |     React.useCallback(() => {
  26 |       fetchData();
  27 |     }, [fetchData])
```

Related test is as follows:

```
import { Home } from './Home';

jest.mock('hooks/Auth/useLoadAuthStudentsData', () => ({
  useLoadAuthStudentData: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('hooks/Student/useStudents', () => ({
  useStudents: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('@react-navigation/core', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/core'),
    useNavigation: jest.fn(() => ({}))
  };
});

const useLoadAuthStudentsData = userHook as ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>;
const useStudents = tasksHook as ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>;

  describe('Home', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    useStudents.mockReturnValue({
      data: Student.deserializeAsList(studentsStub),
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: true,
      isError: false
    });
    useLoadAuthUserData.mockReturnValue({ data: studentStub });
  });

  it('should render screen without error', () => {
    expect(render(<Home />)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should render loader if data is loading', () => {
    useStudents.mockReturnValue({
      data: undefined,
      isLoading: true,
      isSuccess: undefined,
      isError: undefined
    });

    const { getByTestId } = render(<Home />);

    expect(getByTestId('students-layout')).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try changing this:

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/core', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/core'),
    useNavigation: jest.fn(() => ({}))
  };
});
```

to:

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native'),
    useNavigation: jest.fn(() => ({}))
  };
});
```

if that's not enough then make sure the screen is wrapped in a navigation container and navigator, since the hook relies on the component being part of the navigation stack

Comment: Same error. `Home` component is wrapped in `StackScreenProps` like this: type NavProps = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, ROUTES.HOME>;

export const Home: FC<NavProps> = () => {........}
Does it require anything further?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was fixed by this:

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native'),
    useFocusEffect: jest.fn(() => ({})),
  };
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).